# Issue Deploying Rails App to Heroku JWT auth.rb located in the Lib folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, jwt

[image]
I'm trying to host an Rails API on Heroku and I'm having an issue when I sign up a user. Say's there's an error on Line 29. Line 29 is

`jwt = Auth.encrypt({ user_id: @user_id })`

Which makes a call to my Auth class, which isn't located in my `project/app` folder at all, but located outside in my `project/lib/auth.rb`. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If this works in dev, then yes, the issue is probably that the file is located under `lib` and Rails hasn't been configured to autoload files from that path.

You can either get rails to autoload files within lib by setting the following in your `application.rb` file:

`config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`

Or, alternatively you can add `require 'auth'` in your `user_controller.rb`.